# I can't create a new article and edit articles in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I uploaded Joomla 1.5 to my host and install it. And I work in Joomla control panel .
I added some articles.

I had some problems that I fixed. For example when I wanted to visit my site(fa.backyou.com), I saw this error: This URL is not valid and cannot be loaded.

Fortunately, I fixed that problem.

But now I have another problem:
NEW link and EDIT link for articles is broken.
And I can't create a new article and edit articles.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean on the frontend or in the admin backend?

Comment: if you'd explain how did you fix the first problem it could help figuring out the second.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in the backend this sounds like a bad installation. Try reinstalling Joomla again. If this is in the frontend then you probably don't have sufficient privileges to edit and add new articles.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old issue. I encountered the same problem, although my Joomla is on version 3.8.

You may check the source of the problem by setting error reporting to maximum in the Global Configuration via Global Configuration > Server Tab > Error Reporting. From there, I saw that the problem was caused by a plugin, which was not used. I deactivated the plugin- this fixed the problem.

Here's the link to the question I also posted:
[Why can't I add or edit Joomla articles after Global Check In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386675/why-cant-i-add-or-edit-joomla-articles-after-global-check-in/)