# Why can't I add or edit Joomla articles after Global Check In

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using Joomla 3.8 to manage our community website (on the side pro bono). Everything was going well until I noticed an article with a padlock icon in the administration. I applied Global Check In, which unlocked the article. But now I find that I am unable to add or edit articles. Please see screenshot below:
[image]

The website is running on PHP version 5.6.31, with web server Apache.

How do I fix the problem? Is there any code I need to tweek?

Comment: Should I switch to WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I determined the source of the problem. On the administration, I raised the error reporting to maximum:
Global Configuration > Server tab > Error Reporting (changed from System Default to Maximum)

I saw the following errors:
Notice: Undefined variable: plugin in */home5//public_html/plugins/system/connectdaily/connectdaily.php on line 42

Fatal error: Call to a member function logError() on null in /home5//public_html/plugins/system/connectdaily/connectdaily.php on line 42*

I deactivated the connectdaily plugin. The fix worked. I am now able to add and edit articles again.

I am still not sure where the connectdaily plugin is used for. If ever the website will need it, I will just reinstall the plugin.